# Return records where at least 2 or more boolean columns are 'true' in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores information about vendors. In it, there about 10 boolean columns that indicate what departments the vendor belongs to. The vendor can belong to more than one department.

How do I query the table to find any vendors that have more than one of the boolean columns marked true?

My `tbl_vendor_departments` Columns:

`vendor_id` (varchar) `vendor_name` (varchar) `clothing`(bool) `automotive`(bool) `lawn_garden`(bool) `tools`(bool)... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think booleans are actually treated as tiny ints (0 or 1). In that case, you can add up all boolean fields and check if the result > 1.

```
....
WHERE
  clothing + automotive + lawn_garden + .... + tools > 1
```

Answer (score 5):

In MySQL, boolean is just an integer 0 or 1.  So you can then use arithmetic:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tbl_vendor_departments
WHERE (clothing + automotive + lawn_garden + tools) >= 2
```

Strictly speaking, in MySQL zero is false and any non-zero value is true.  So you could get unexpected results if your "boolean" columns contain true values larger values than 1 (e.g. 42).  To compensate, you can invert true values to false, and then invert again.  This should convert 42 to 0 and then back to 1.  Use parentheses to control operator precedence.

```
SELECT ...
FROM tbl_vendor_departments
WHERE (
    (NOT NOT clothing) +
    (NOT NOT automotive) +
    (NOT NOT lawn_garden) +
    (NOT NOT tools)
) >= 2
```

Don't try this with other SQL implementations, though.  Most do not implement `boolean` in a way that is compatible with integer arithmetic, so the above query would (and should, per ANSI SQL) generate an error.  For those, you could use CASE expressions to convert from true to 1:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tbl_vendor_departments
WHERE (
    CASE clothing    WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE automotive  WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE lawn_garden WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE tools       WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) >= 2
```

Comment: Excellent answer and super informative as well. I would check as the answer but Golez Trol did get to it first and it did work... +1 for sure though.

Comment: Yep, I was typing my answer when @GolezTrol posted his.  He/she gets credit for being quicker!  :)

Comment: Whoa! I would never have thought of the double `NOT` statement. Nice bit of structured query witchcraft there.

Comment: The whole concept of using math in general also escaped me completely. I was fixating on other solutions when the answer was right in front of me.

Comment: And you get points for typing the extra information. The `not not` is a smart trick. You could also type `(clothing <> 0)` or `if(clothing, 1, 0)` as well. But in practise, I wonder if it is true what you say. Of course, any non 0 value is treated as true, but I don't think a boolean field will ever contain a value other than 1. It would be possible though, since bool is a synonym for tinyint, which is a signed 8 bit value. So if in any doubt of your data is either 0 or 1, use this solution over mine.

Comment: Right, declaring a "bool" type in MySQL is just an alias for `tinyint(1)` although it can still take any signed 8-bit integer (-128 to 127).  The `(1)` is meaningless.

Comment: For the record, I do have it set as a `tinyint` and hardcoded the variable to be '1' when the user inserts/updates the record - just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is a guaranteed feature (but suspect that it is) but boolean fields set to true will, in my experience, always be 1 and when false, zero. So just adding all the fields up and selecting the records where the total is 2 or more will do the job.